# How to setup filebeat monitoring via stack monitoring in kibana?

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

I'm trying to setup monitoring for filebeat via kibana stack monitoring ui. But when I tried to do this, I'm unsble to see the filebeat stats on this page, I can just see ELK stack stats.

This's my filebeat.yml config

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true 
  paths:
    - /logs/*.log 

  multiline.pattern: '^\s|^\]'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after  

monitoring:
  enabled: false
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["elk_ip:9200"]

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["elk_ip:5044"]
  index: "filebeat"
```

Now when I start my elk stack which's on a different machine and filebeat, I'm only able to see ELK stack stats and not beats stats. I'm however able to send logs to kibana via logstash and elasticsearch from my filebeat and able to verify the same.

[image]

Can someone please help with how I can configure beats stats in my stack monitoring ui?

Answer (score 0):

```
monitoring:
  enabled: false
```

This doesn't look like what you want. Does it work when you set it to `true`?